# Neo4J custom load CSV

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, load

I asked a question a few days ago to know how to import an existing database into Neo4J. Thanks to the person who explained me how to do that. I decided to create a CSV file from my database (around 1 million entries) and to load it from the Neo4j webadmin to test it. The problem is that each row of this database contains redundant data, for example my database contains actions from different users but each user can do mutliple actions. The structure of my graph would be to create a node for each user that is linked to each action he does. That's why I have to create only one node for each user even if his name appears in several rows of my CSV file (because he made several actions). What is the method to do that ? I guess it's possible to do that in Cypher right ?
Thanks a lot
Regards
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have references that might or might not exist, you should use the `MERGE` statement. `MERGE` either finds something or creates something in your database.

Please refer to the respective section in the reference manual: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html. Here the country is shared my multiple users there the country is merged wheres the users and their relationships to countries are unconditionally created.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer. It seems to work using the MERGE statement but on the Neo4j web interface it take a lot of time (about 9 minutes) to deal with about 150,000 rows of the CSV file (that creates only 1500 different nodes) and I have another problem I'm often getting disconnected from Neo4j, maybe it's because of the running time ? Thanks Stefan

Comment: Sam can you share your exact query? You should use `periodic commit` and also make sure you have no `Eager` step in between, that one pulls all rows in in one go to separate reads from previous writes.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. I don't know where but there must be a problem. I'm loading a CSV file that contains names of user and events they are making. Of course a user makes several events so the first thing as explained above is to create nodes with names of users without redundancy (even if they appears in more than a row). That is done with MERGE command and it works in about 1 minute. Then I'm trying to create nodes for every events, therefore there must be a many nodes than rows in my CSV file. To achieve that I'm using the following code:

Comment: using periodic commit load csv with headers from "file:/Users/sam/test.csv" as layer2 create(l{event_classification: layer2.enventclassification})

Comment: This code takes about 15 minutes to run on in the Neo4j Webinterface and as explained above there must be only 150,000 nodes. My comuputer is powerful enough so it can't be the problem. The problem after that is to create relationships between users and events they made. Do you have any idea how to do that ? Because remember that I used MERGE command to create nodes with users and CREATE commande to create nodes with events. The goal is to link each user to different events they made.

Comment: Plz provide the header line plus couple of (anonymized) rows of your csv.

Comment: Here is the header of my CSV file. It is composed by a lot of unuseful fields.

Comment: id,eventid,time,evo,classification,severity,description,conf,reference,additionaldata,orig,ruleid,ruonary,rufile,actiontax,outcometax,hostname,location,address,address_ip,addressmail,address_mac,netmask,service_name,service_config,service_component,service_description,service_resource,serviceport,userid,username,userdomain,usergroup,userprivilege,processname,processpid,processarg,processenv,ihostname,ilocation,iinitiatortax,iaddress_name,iaddress_ip,iemail,imac,inetmask,iservice_name,iservice_component,iservice_description,iservice_resource,iserviceport,iuserid,iusername,

Comment: iuser_domain,iuser_group,iprivilege,iprocess_name,ipid,iarg,ienv,thostname,tlocation,ttargettax,taddress_name,taddressip,temail,tmac,tnetmask,tservicename,tservicecomponent,tdescription,tsresource,tserviceport,tuid,tusername,tuserdomain,tusergroup,tprivilege,tprocess_name,tpid,targ,tenv

Comment: I'd try to strip down the number of columns in the csv to a minimum viable set to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hello, I guess the problem comes from elsewhere. Actually I gain some time to create nodes when I remove unuseful colums. But I can't create relationships between these nodes. I think I'm doing something wrong to create these relationships. My CSV file (simplified) is the following:

Comment: id,user,1,user1,2,user1,3,user1,4,user1,5,user2,6,user2

Comment: We can see that user1 did actions 1,2,3,4 and user2 did actions 5 and 6. My goal is to browse the CSV file and first create only 2 nodes for users. To achieve this I used MERGE command. Then to create events I used CREATE command. The goal is to link each event to users that is responsible for.

Comment: I guess to achieve that I have to browse the CSV file again but I don't know how to do exactly. Could you please give me any idea ? Thank you very much. Sam